# use orderBy for value in array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have nested ng-repeat that extracts data from the server:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in result | filter:sellbox " >
               <div ng-repeat="z in x.data | orderBy:'??' "  >


           {{x.rate_type}} to {{x.name}}  {{z[1]}}
       </div>

        </div>
```

This is part of the server:

```
 "result":[  
      {  
         "id":"BNLN_USD",
         "code":"BNLN",
         "name":"National Bank Of Georgia (BNLN)",
         "currency":"USD",
         "rate_type":"reference",
         "color":"#4b4a4b",
         "legendIndex":1,
         "data":[  
            [  
               1473033600000,
               2.2938
            ]
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"BAGA_USD_B",
         "code":"BAGA",
         "name":"Bank Of Georgia  (BAGA)",
         "currency":"USD",
         "rate_type":"buy",
         "color":"#ed7623",
         "dashStyle":"shortdot",
         "legendIndex":2,
         "data":[  
            [  
               1473033600000,
               2.25
            ]
         ]
      }
```

z[1] is giving the value of 2.2938 and 2.25 in this segment. How do I use orderBy so that the results are ordered in decreasing order of z[1].

Answer (score 1):

Since AngularJS 1.3.0-rc.5, the `orderBy` filter will automatically sort the array using its items if no additional parameters are provided.

`<div ng-repeat="z in x.data | orderBy">{{item}}</div>`

Comment: Not in my case :)

Comment: Note: If you notice numbers not being sorted as expected, make sure they are actually being saved as numbers and not strings.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you couldn't **orderBy** was that your **data** is an array of array, so you have to call a custom orderBy function.

In your controller

```
$scope.customOrder = function (content) {
     return content.sort()[0]; 
}
```

In your HTML pass the customOrder function and pass true to make it descending

```
<div ng-repeat="x in result | filter:sellbox " >
  <div ng-repeat="z in x.data | orderBy:customOrder:true">
       {{x.rate_type}} to {{x.name}}  {{z[1]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's missing here,  so that i can help it out

Comment: It doesn't say that anything is missing. I implemented everything as you said and console logged some lines to check if customOrder is working (it is). Is the return content the thing we need?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by mapping my results:

JS:

```
$rootScope.bank_data = $rootScope.result.map(function(x){

  return {
      rate_type: x.rate_type,
      name: x.name,
      value :x.data[0][1]

         };
})
```

HTML:

```
<input type="searchbox" ng-model="sellbox" ng-hide="buy"  >
          <div ng-repeat="m in bank_data | filter:sellbox | orderBy:'-value'" > {{m.rate_type}} {{m.name}} {{m.value}}</div>
```

This way I managed to display the array I wanted to sort and it worked just fine. Thank you everyone for helping.